# Incorrect decrement of the reference count

Tags: xcode, ios, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm getting an incorrect decrement of the reference count for the filemanager object.

```
-(void) checkDb{
BOOL success;
// Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status of the database and to copy it over if required
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if (success)
{
    //we found the file, we need to check version
    sqlite3 *db;
    //NSLog(@"Current Databasepath: %@",dbPath);
    // Open the current db (found in the user's filessytem)
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql = "select dbversion from settings";
        sqlite3_stmt *rs;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,  sql, -1, &rs, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(rs) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //not eof
                int curDbVersion=sqlite3_column_int(rs,0);
                if (curDbVersion>=minDbVersion){
                    //good dbversion, no need to copy from resources
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(rs);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

//we reached this section which means:
//either database was not found, or invalid db version
//so, we need to copy it from the resources directory (or maybe download it from internet?)

// Get the path to the database in the application package
NSString *dbPathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

// Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:nil];

[fileManager release];
```

}

The program is running perfectly, but when I analyze it, I'm getting a warning.

Here's a screenshot of the warning that I'm getting:

[image: Original: grab.by/ahSi]

Any hints of what might have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the line where you're creating your fileManager pointer:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

The words `copy`, `new`, `alloc`, or `retain` are nowhere to be found: you don't own the fileManager, therefore you should not release it.

Your last line:

```
[fileManager release];
```

is effectively trying to release the `defaultFileManager`, which you certainly don't own.

Comment: thanks alot, now i understand it better.. i've been into ios development since 2 weeks only.. and digging it.. cheers..

Answer (score 1):

Don't `release` the file manager -- it's a local variable and will be automatically released later.

Comment: +1 for "don't release the file manager," but the reason doesn't have anything to do with the scope of the variable. It's just that the code doesn't alloc, copy, or retain the file manager and therefore has no business releasing it.